# What should be in the controller to update records from this params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably a simple question.  I'm reading the form helpers guide on rubyonrails.org ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html ).  In section 7.3 it shows how to make a form that returns a hash of params like the following:

```
 {'person' => {'name' => 'Bob', 'address' => {'23' => {'city' => 'Paris'}, '45' => {'city' => 'London'}}}}
```

Bob has 2 addresses in the hash.  So what goes in the controller in order to update both addresses for Bob at the same time?

Thanks.

Update:

Here's what I assume the models would look like, but I still don't know what the controller should look like to update both of Bob's addresses simultaneously.

person.rb

```
attr_accessible :name, :addresses_attributes 

has_many :addresses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
```

address.rb

```
attr_accessible :city

belongs_to :person
```

Thank you.

Comment: try reading the rails associations and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. these two will help you.

Comment: I've read that too and did not find an answer to this specific question.  I know how to update records 1 at a time but I don't know how to do it when there are 2 records to update.

Comment: I updated above with what I think the models should look like with nested attributes.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conventionally, I can suggest to try the followings:

```
def update
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  if @person.update_attributes(parmas[:person])
    #update successful, now do what you wanna do
  else 
    #update was unsuccessful 
  end
end
```

Try this and get back if you get any error. But this is not probably right way to learn things. You should follow the [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and subsequent tutorials.

Comment: Right. I was confusing a few different issues I wasn't clear on, but I see that this should update correctly with inputs from a form_for fields_for nested form.  Here is the problem I am really trying to solve though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245182/editing-nested-collection-through-1-form-in-rails.  Do you think you can help with that one?  My research on how to solve this issue led me to ask this new question above but it ultimately didn't help me solve the original issue.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out so don't waste your time looking.  Thank you for helping me understand some things that led me to the answer.